# When to sqlite3_close in iOS apps

Tags: ios, sqlite

I'm using Sqlite 3 in my iOS Game to persist/load user scores for every mission they accomplish (I got over 4k missions). My need is very basic; I have only one sqlite table, I load and cache all scores into memory at startup (memory footprint does not exceed 130k in the worst case), and then I perform a simple update/insert into the database with a frequency of say once/5 minutes.

My questions:

- Should I `sqlite3_open()` and `sqlite3_close()` the database for every transaction, or open it at launch and keep it live to close it only when the app terminates?
- Is there a significant memory cost to keeping the database open?
- Is there a risk of damaging data if the app crashes while the database is open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the database when the app goes into the foreground and close it when the app goes into the background (that's not the same as launch/closedown).  Also build re-opening logic into the method that gets the database handle, so you can close it anytime you like (i.e. memory warning) and it will always attempts to re-open when you want to use it next.  You seem to have spotted that you don't want to open/close the database for every query you want to perform as it's slightly expensive.
2. Not really; nothing compared to the size of a small image though.  A file handle or two, some cache memory.  Don't worry about it.
3. Yes.  You can mitigate that risk using transactions, however that shouldn't be necessary unless you are really worried about corruption.

Comment: Thanks @trojanfoe That perfectly answers my questions. I'm interested in learning more about transactions though, do you have a link on the subject?

Comment: @ALTN It's pretty straight forward. See the [sqlite3 site](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html).  It's pretty much only used when inserting into multiple tables that represent one "transaction".  If something goes wrong you don't want any of the inserts to "stick".  It probably won't make any difference when inserting/updating into a single table.

Comment: does that mean the risk of corruption could only occur if the app crashes while communicating with the database? I was actually worried if just keeping it open after an eventual crash preventing a close call, could cause data damage... maybe I'm worrying too much? Anyways thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you are worrying too much.  It can generally look after itself, unless you use certain commands that can increase performance.  Then it starts becoming vulnerable to corruption.  Out-of-the-box, though, it'll be fine.